# Changing the meaning of sentence by grammar

Tags: meaning, grammar, wish-preterite

I would like to ask for meaning of the two following sentence, and whether or not is the grammar correct. Please check my suggestions both "sentences" and meanings.

**"I wish I never met you."** - I met you just now but I do not want to meet you at all (from now to the future). So I wish not to meet you in the future anymore.

**"I wish I would have never met you."** - I regret the day when I have met you. It has happened very long time ago. It was mistake and I regret the fact that I know you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sentences mean the same thing. They are speaking on how you lament the moment you met the person.
If you wish to say that you never want to see the person again, consider, "I wish to never meet you again." This however would probably never be used in real life since it is extremely rude.

Comment: So what is the difference between the two sentences I wrote since they mean the same thing? The second one is more polite?

Comment: @Lentan, I think it depends on the way the sentence is written for whatever meaning you happen to be in, that's all.

Comment: @Elberich Schneider Fits for the explanation of the second sentence "I wish I had never met you."?

Comment: "I wish I would have never met you." I have never heard this usage. Depending on the time factor, better options will be, I wish I never met you, or,  I wish I had never met you.

Comment: I wouldn't say either of them, though I know that some people would. The only way to say that counter-factual grammatically in my idiolect is _I wish I had never met you_.